# SQL Exception - Login failed for user "UserName$"

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am having an issue with one of my pages that is pulling content from a database which is displayed in `<select>` tags. I have seen many others with this issue but haven't seen anyone's have a $ after the user. I am not sure why it is adding a $. I have redone my connection string, .dbml file and have even created a user AD\INFO4420$ in my database and have given it read and write privileges. When using Visual Studios I am able to run the page and there is no error but it only occurs when viewing it from the server.

The Error is as follows:

> Login failed for user 'AD\INFO4420W$'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed
>   for user 'AD\INFO4420W$'.

Connection String in my Web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Final_Project-20131204200025;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Final_Project-20131204200025.mdf"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="TowingApp_dbConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=INFO4420W.ad.uvu.edu;Initial Catalog=TowingApp_db; Integrated Security=true"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I know the program is using the following as the connection string. Any time I comment out the following it throws another error.

```
<add name="TowingApp_dbConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=INFO4420W.ad.uvu.edu;Initial Catalog=TowingApp_db; Integrated Security=true"
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Any help or direction would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked whether a Windows-authentication SQL Server login for `AD\INFO4420W$` actually exists?

Comment: @J0e3gan AD\4420W$ was never there and I am not sure why it is using it. But I have added it as a user in the DB but it wouldn't allow me to make a Login because of the $ which it won't accept as a valid symbol

Comment: It is using `AD\4420W$` because you have `Integrated Security=true`, which means it will use Windows authentication and the Windows credentials of the process connecting to SQL Server; and the app pool of the site is presumably running under Windows account `AD\4420W$`.

Comment: You need a server login rather than a database user - at least to start.  Server logins and database users are often confused but are distinct.  If you create a local Windows account `Test$` then add a new Windows-authenticaton server login for it, you will see that a Windows-auth server login for a username with a `$` in it is indeed possible.

Comment: So I Create a SQL Auth. User and deleted my DBML file along with my connection string. Re-created both using the SQL Authenticated user and it worked. It automatically inserted the UserID and password. I appreciate the responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using integrated security `Integrated Security=true`. It works locally because your local windows account has access to local SQL Server DB. Perhaps you have to switch to SQL Server authentication with dedicated ID and password.

In that case instead of `Integrated Security=true` you would specify

```
User ID=YourUserid;Password=YourPassword;
```

My guess the ID/Password should be provided to you by the univercity. Also to avoid having ID and password in open text either supply them from code or encrypt the connection string.

Comment: Would I add the domain as well? `User ID=AD\USERNAME;Password=YourPassword;` ? and Why would it be adding a $ at the end, the Username is INFO4420W?

Comment: I think it's an identity under which ASP.NET App pool is running. And no, for SQL Server authentication it will be just UserID/PW, no domain

Comment: You may prefer to switch to SQL Server authentication, but you should not have to.